# How to delete empty source directories when moving folders with rsync?

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, zsh

`rsync` can be coaxed into moving folders very similarly and superiorly to traditional `mv` with the following options:

```
rsync -axvvES --remove-source-files source_directory /destination/
```

However one thing I cannot yet seem to get it to do is to remove original directories.  The `--remove-source-files` flag does just that, removes the source files, but not also source directories.  I wish there were a `--remove-source-directories` flag as well, but there's not.

**How can I deal with this?**  I suppose I can just issue an `rm -fr` after the move, however I'd prefer to keep the procedure all in one process vs introducing a potential for mistakes.

Comment: What is your reason for not using `mv`?

Comment: Different volumes and I need to preserve all attributes, including times.

Comment: Same need here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78375/3858.

Comment: I'm very surprised rsync has no option for this, especially when it does at the destination side. I end up doing `find . -type d -empty | xargs rmdir -p`

Comment: You know @Sridhar-Sarnobat I can't help but wonder if there's a way to pass results from an `rsync` session into a list that is then processed following the process that then cleans it up... Hmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a command that does that in one go, but since rsync still performs better than `rm -rf` (specially if you have a very large number of directories) here are two rsync command that do a *"move"*:

```
rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files source/ destination/ && \
rsync -av --delete `mktemp -d`/ source/ && rmdir source/
```

Answer (score 22):

I ended up in a similar situation. I wanted to avoid `rm -rf`, knowing that rsync failed to copy some files, and I didn't want to loose them.

To simply delete the empty directories, I found this one the most convenient (from `sourcedir`):

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: Yep, thank goodness for -empty, which I only found out recently and it's become very common for me to use.

Comment: Thank @lp_ This one should be updated as the best answer

Answer (score 7):

Using "**rm -rf**" has an inherent race condition, you could namely delete files that were just created between the **rsync** and the **rm** invocations.

I prefer to use:

```
rsync --remove-source-files -a server:incoming/ incoming/ && 
ssh server find incoming -depth -type d -delete
```

This will NOT remove the directories if they are not empty.

Comment: Note you apparently may need to add `-depth` on OSX or others.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieGorichanaz, done

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add `rm -rf source_directory` after your rsync ?

```
rsync -axvvES --remove-source-files source_directory /destination/ && rm -rf source_directory
```

Each command-line program is (idealy) made to do a specified task, and it's up to you to glue several together to accomplish more complex tasks.

Comment: I think you're right.  I believe I ultimately have to drill down to the bottom as well first as I cannot get caught just moving the way rsync normally does.  Probably need to use `find -depth`.  Would you have any suggestion as to a quick algorithmic approach to getting down to the bottom of the dir stack, mv'ing with rsync, rm'ing as you note, and then stepping back up the tree?